# Data recovery from memory card for undeleted files that are not visible

Tags: windows-7, windows, data-recovery, file-recovery

I had a memory card from a friend and we were trying to copy some pics to and fro my laptop.

**TL,DR:** Need a software to recover undeleted files from a MMC.  That's right, I need to do *undeleted* files recovery.

**OS:** Windows 7 Home Premium

**What happened:** While copying, I got an error that the disc is not present.  After clicking on Retry, windows asked me to check the disc and reported its not the same disc that was inserted earlier.  I had to cancel finally because nothing else was working.

**What did I try:** I tried Recuva and restored 436 files.  She said they were pics of a trip from 5 months earlier and no pics were recovered from her last vacation that were present on memory card before MMC corrupted

I did notice 5 files recovered from the set that we wanted to recover.  These were the files that we "cut" and pasted. Logically, deleted from MMC before it got corrupted

**My logic of what happened:** The files that were deleted (from her trips earlier and the ones that i "cut") were recovered.  This may have happened because the softwares tried to recover only deleted files.

**What I need:** Some software that searches for undeleted files and recover.  Every google search and forum research that I have tried talks about undeleting files.

I dont want to experiment with the card's current state without extracting the files first.  If anyone knows about same case happened somewhere else, please let me know what did you try that worked

Comment: try [GetDataBack](http://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm). I didnt put this as an answer because Im not sure if it will work with a memory card or not

Comment: At this point you might have to accept they cannot be recovered.  MMC devices handle files being deleted in a different way.  As for the question itself asking for a list of software to use is not on topic for this website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec), which works natively on many operating systems, and works with all Windows and Linux filesystems.  If the filesystem itself is corrupted, you can also use complement software [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) (from the same company) which can repair and recover an entire filesystem if possible.  Both of these tools are free, open source, and cross platform.  From the website:

> PhotoRec ignores the file system and goes after the underlying data,
>   so it will still work even if your media's file system has been
>   severely damaged or reformatted.